# Sum of Binomial Coefficient products

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, binomial-coefficients, random

I am trying to prove that

$$\sum\limits_{y=0}^d \frac{{2x \choose y} {2d-2x \choose d-y} }{2d \choose d} = x $$

So far, I have tried using induction on $d$ but I am having trouble using the inductive hypothesis since the $d$ appears in the summation term as well. Does anyone have a more intuitive way of tackling this problem?

Comment: See [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity), and try to approach this problem along similar lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide two answers and you may decide if they could be considered as *intuitive*. The first answer is a geometrically based *combinatorial proof* the second  is based upon Egorychev's *formal residual calculus for power series* (and may also be considered intuitive if you like to play with generating functions).

> - First answer using **lattice pathes**:
>
> The number $\binom{n}{k}$ can be considered as the number of lattice pathes of *length* $n$ containing $k$ horizontal $(1,0)$-steps and $n-k$ vertical $(0,1)$-steps.

This is valid because there are $\binom{n}{k}$ choices to select $k$ steps in horizontal direction leaving the remaining $n-k$ steps for the vertical direction.

> Let's apply this approach to the identity:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum\limits_{y=0}^d\binom{2x}{y}\binom{2d-2x}{d-y}=\binom{2d}{d}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We consider lattice pathes starting at $(0,0)$ with length $2d$ containing $d$ $(1,0)$-steps and $d$ $(0,1)$-steps. These pathes are all within a square with sides of length $d$. The number of these pathes is $$\binom{2d}{d}$$
To interpret the left hand side of (1) we select an $x$ with $0\leq x\leq d$ and *partition* the $\binom{2d}{d}$ pathes as follows: For each path we consider the *head* of length $2x$, i.e. the first $2x$ steps of the path and the corresponding *tail* of length $2d-2x$. Now we *partition* the pathes according to the number $y$ of horizontal $(1,0)$ -steps in the *head*.

> The number of sub-pathes (*heads*) with length $2x$ having $y$ $(1,0)$-steps is

$$\binom{2x}{y}$$

For each of these sub-pathes we can choose a sub-path of length $2d-2x$ (*tail*) with $d-y$ horizontal steps to get a complete path with length $2d$ from $(0,0)$ to $(d,d)$.

> So, the number of all pathes from $(0,0)$ to $(d,d)$ with *head* of length $2x$ containing $y$ horizontal steps is

$$\binom{2x}{y}\binom{2d-2x}{d-y}$$

Since $y$ may vary between $0$ and $2x$ provided $d-y \geq 0$ we get $0 \leq y \leq d$ and

> the number $\binom{2d}{d}$ of *all* pathes from $(0,0)$ to $(d,d)$ is according to this partition:
>   $$\sum\limits_{y=0}^d\binom{2x}{y}\binom{2d-2x}{d-y}$$

And here's the

> - Second answer using Egorychevs **formal residual calculus for power series**

This powerful technique is based upon [Cauchys residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and was introduced by *G.P. Egorychev* ([Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](http://www.amazon.de/Representation-Computation-Combinatorial-Translations-Mathematical/dp/0821845128)) to compute binomial identies.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=0}^{d}&\binom{2x}{y}\binom{2d-2x}{d-y}\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\binom{2x}{y}\binom{2d-2x}{d-y}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\mathop{res}_u\frac{(1+u)^{2x}}{u^{y+1}}
\mathop{res}_w\frac{(1+w)^{2d-2x}}{w^{d-y+1}}\tag{2}\\
&=\mathop{res}_w\frac{(1+w)^{2d-2x}}{w^{d+1}}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}w^y\mathop{res}_u\frac{(1+u)^{2x}}{u^{y+1}}\tag{3}\\
&=\mathop{res}_w\frac{(1+w)^{2d-2x}}{w^{d+1}}(1+w)^{2x}\tag{4}\\
&=\mathop{res}_w\frac{(1+w)^{2d}}{w^{d+1}}\\
&=\binom{2d}{d}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) the limit is changed without affecting the sum, since only $0$ is added.
- In (2) the residual calculus of formal power series is applied for each binomial coefficient.
- In (3) there is some rearrangement to prepare the application of the *substitution rule* which is used in (4)

You may want to have a look at my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917115/identity-with-catalan-numbers/939512) to read a small introductory note to this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
\begin{align}
S_{m} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2x}{k} \binom{2m-2x}{m-k}
\end{align}
for which it can be seen as the following.
\begin{align}
S_{m} &= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m-2x}{m} \frac{(-m)_{k}(-2x)_{k}}{k! (m-2x+1)_{k}} \\
&= \binom{2m-2x}{m} {}_{2}F_{1}(-m, -2x; m-2x+1; 1) \\
&= \binom{2m-2x}{m} \frac{(m-2x)! (2m)!}{(2m-2x)! m!} \\
&= \binom{2m}{m}.
\end{align}
From this it is seen that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{\binom{2x}{k} \binom{2m-2x}{m-k}}{\binom{2m}{m}} = 1.
\end{align}